# Microsoft access attachment to c# picturebox

Tags: c#

When I connect access to C# forms everything work well but I can't connect attachment file to picturebox. I get an error messagebox with this text: `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

[image]

```
byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])reader.GetValue(6);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
Bitmap p = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms));
poto.Image = p;
```

Comment: try to add ms.Position = 0; after ms.write ....

Comment: @777chubinidze exactly *what* throws that error? Could you show us some more code?

Comment: I want to load picture from access attachment.this is code : field 
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {   byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])reader.GetValue(6);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    Bitmap p = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms));
                    poto.Image = p;

Comment: It's most likely your `reader.GetValue(6);` call that throws the error. Are you absolutely sure that there are 7 columns returned by the reader/command?

Comment: I'm sorry this was 5th field , I changed but now I get : "uneble to cast object of type 'system.string' to type 'system.byte[ ]'

Comment: The index is 0-based, if you want the 5th field, use index `4`

Comment: i know ,there are 6 field and this field index is 5 , I changed but now I get : "uneble to cast object of type 'system.string' to type 'system.byte[ ]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to assign image directly from stream

```
byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])reader.GetValue(6); 
comm = new OleDbCommand(sqlCommand, sqlConnection);
ImageByte = comm.ExecuteScalar();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ImageByte);
poto.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

If you still getting error:

> unable to cast object of type 'system.string' to type 'system.byte[]'

Maybe you have an issue in your sql query. Debug and check the output

```
MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(6).ToString());
```